# Compare a new record with old records to avoid duplication

Tags: apex

I want an example how to compare a new record with old records in order to prevent duplicated records from being inserted.

For example: When I insert a new 'Time Off', I compare the new start date and end date if there is already a requested time off, then an error message will be displayed as:

> This Start / End date is already asked. Please choose another start/end date

I've created a field named: `WFError__c` in my object as unique field (TEXT type), then I created a workflow on my custom object (`Time_Off__c`) there for I created a field update action on that `WFError__c` with this formula value `TEXT( Start_date__c ) + TEXT( End_date__c )`.

Comment: welcomes to salesforce.Stackexchange Kawtar. Have you already tried to write something in Apex yourself ? It would be meaningful to see that. Some more information on your datamodel and business concept may also help. You can edit the question to add more details.

Comment: I want to use trigger for that matter, to display the error, but I'm not using a VisualForce page, I'm working with a standard page. I have in mind that oldMap.keySet() and newMap.keySet() obtain the diffetent ID's (old and new records) of an object, but I need an example to see how it works. I have a custom object: Time_Off__c custom fields: Start_date__c and End_date__c.

Comment: There is an APEX trigger recipe - http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/preventing-duplicate-records-from-saving worth checking.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do this with triggers, you could achieve it by creating a new text field as unique and use field update workflow to fill this field by the concatenation of your Start and End date. 
The error will be something standard like the following image : 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the idea! but I'm working on Date field here, not a Text. And trigger operate just in update and delete action. in my case it would be a before insert action

Comment: You can concatenate the date or the date time in a workflow using the TEXT() function. and triggers can be fired on before insert event too

Comment: I'm talking about the use of oldMap, it's working just on update and delete event. but I still can't get your answer. can you please explain it further more!

Comment: @melmoussaoui It's tempting to use unique text fields but in that one I'd have to carefully test it. I predict some "fun" when you cast DateTime to string like that - will it respect timezones?

Comment: @KawtarBrazi OldMap in triggers you could use it only to compare records stats before and after your update
@ eyescream that what I'm afraid from.

Comment: It's not working!!

Comment: @KawtarBrazi Could you tell us what you did by updating your initiale question?

Comment: I did exactly what you said.. See my edit

Comment: @KawtarBrazi You should use & for concatenate and not + and I just tested it and it works just fine (WFError__c content in my case : '2014-05-05 13:16:00Z2014-05-05 13:16:00Z'

Comment: That is not the problem, the concatenation is Ok, but the displaying error is not showing up!!

Comment: If you have a record let say : Start date = 2014-05-05 17:44 and End Date 2014-05-05 18:44 then if you try to create another recored with the same info you should be stopped by Salesforce